# Are static lambdas of any use/unwise?

Tags: c++11, lambda

I'm trying to track a very difficult to reproduce bug. I have a pool of items and use the following to automatically check the pool items back in when the client has finished with them:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<T> Handle;

Handle MyPool::checkOut()
{
    static const auto CheckInDeleter = [this](T* item)
    {
        this->checkIn(item);
    };

    return Handle(item, CheckInDeleter);
}
```

My question is is this unsafe? Will `this` be assigned to the first pool that checks out an item?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `static` function-scope variables are assigned once,so there will be only one lambda object, that will refer to first `MyPool` that has `checkOut` member function called. It is probably not what you need, so just remove `static`.